# VBA Textbox : after entering each letter its skips to next row and column before entering the full word

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that I'm using in VBA which I'm entering data into a excel sheet via a VBA form which will populate the excel sheet vertical and horizontal at the same time but each time i enter a letter it skips to the next column and row without full entering the word before submit in the form. How can I solve this please.

```
Private Sub txtLocation_Change()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Location")
  Dim newRow As Long
  newRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
  newCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:H")) + 1
  ws.Cells(newRow, 1).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
  ws.Cells(1, newRow).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
End Sub
```

This is what showing up

[image]

Comment: The event fires every time the contents changes, such as adding a single letter.

Comment: Yes. Following what @CLR said, remove the code from the `Change` event of the `txtLocation` box and use a command button to update the text box value (once fully entered).

Answer (score 0):

The function uses the `CountA` function to count how many rows exist and adds a value after the last row.

The next time the function is executed the `CountA` will count one more row and work on the next row.

Perhaps you want to count the rows when you open the form, only once, and use that number as long as the form is open.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `Change` event, which fires every time a small change is made to the text box.

Instead, consider using the `AfterUpdate` event, which fires once you come away from the field - i.e. finish typing into it and move on.

`Private Sub`**`txtLocation_AfterUpdate()`**

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Location")
  Dim newRow As Long
  newRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
  newCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:H")) + 1
  ws.Cells(newRow, 1).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
  ws.Cells(1, newRow).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help! Give others a chance to provide a better answer if you wish, but when you're happy with whichever answer you need, don't forget to mark it as answered.